# Nhibernate + Spring.Net + Transaction + too many threads

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

I am using Sping.Net 1.3.1 and Nhibernate 3.0.
I use Spring's Transaction Interceptor in order to create my Transactions.
I mark my Transactional methods with the Transaction Attribute.
My server gets something like 20 - 25 requests per second, each request is
handled on a new thread, using parallel's Task.
I run a stress test in order to verify my server capability of handling the calls.
when i run only two or three calls ion a time, every thing works great, **but**
when I run 5 -10 calls simultanly I got an exception from Spring.

The exception is:

```
Spring.Transaction.TransactionSystemException was unhandled by user code
Message=Could not commit Hibernate transaction
Source=Spring.Data.NHibernate30
StackTrace:
  at Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager.DoCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate\Data\NHibernate\HibernateTransactionManager.cs:line 568
  at Spring.Transaction.Support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.ProcessCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status)

InnerException: NHibernate.TransactionException
  Message=Transaction not connected, or was disconnected
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
    at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.CheckNotZombied() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs:line 408
    at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs:line 181
    at Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager.DoCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in c:\_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate\Data\NHibernate\HibernateTransactionManager.cs:line 556
   InnerException:
```

Thank you very much,
Or Chubook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you have already discovered this answer by now. When you share a NHibernate session among multiple threads, you will run into this concurrency problem. Each thread must have their own session in scope in order to avoid a transaction disconnect state.